# Filter list without using SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, web-part, filter

I'm trying to filter a list, something like the OOTB WP, but more flexible. The problem with the webpart is that the user has to input the exact contents of the item he wants to find. I would like the webpart to operate more like a regular search bar. The problem is that at the company I work at I have the search scopes disabled, as well as the share point designer.

Is there a way to do this, maybe with some coding?

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

[image]

Trick is to attach a JavaScript `keyup` event to the existing Searchbox **for every ListItem** (in this case *above* the Searchbox in the DOM, because events bubble up anyway)

Each script can check against any content you can reference in a Calculated Column... that means no enumerables like Person fields or Multiple Select Choices.

If you [stuff it all in a Calculated Column](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How) (set to datatype=Number)

All it takes is:

```
=" <img src=""_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
 & "var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
 & "TR.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.addEventListener('keyup',"
 & "(function(keyevent){"
    & "this.style.backgroundColor='" 
    & [Task Name] 
    & "'.indexOf(keyevent.srcElement.value)===-1?'lightcoral':'lightgreen'}).bind(TR))"
 & "}"">"
```

The whole clue (and JavaScript magic) is the IMG is loaded *inside* the TR, thus `bind(TR)` gives you the correct *this* scope to set the backgroundColor.

Step by step building instructions at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/SearchFilter

You could also do it with SP2013 *Client Side Rendering* code... but that requires some 20 lines more JavaScript boilerplate code.... AND a separate scriptfile... AND a JSlink on **every View** you want to use it.

iCC